# Use external resource (media) in firebase cloud function without storage bucket

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Let's say I have an invoice to generate and the invoice contains the company's logo and other images that would be used each time an invoice is generated.

Would I have to pull those images off the storage bucket? Or can I load it into the `functions` directory and use it from there, similar to how the `serviceaccount.json` file is loaded into functions?

EDIT: The way I'm thinking of is

```
functions/
├── index.js
├── image.jpg
```

And in `index.js`

```
const path = require("path");
const pathToImage = path.join(__dirname,'/image.jpg');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase/Cloud Functions deployment process packs up everything in your `functions` directory, and deploys it to the runtime for your functions. This means that you can indeed include any static files you need in the Cloud Functions deployment, and then access them from your code.

This is how you also include your service account, or what happens when you split your Cloud Functions code over multiple files that you then include into `index.js`.